# Mapping checkbox values to an empty array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have a series of arrays tied to checkboxes.

Here is the HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="value1">Value 1
<input type="checkbox" value="value2">Value 2
<input type="checkbox" value="value3">Value 3
```

In my jQuery I have these arrays defined as follows:

```
var value1 = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
var value2 = ['itemA', 'itemB', 'itemC'];
var value3 = ['item!', 'item@', 'item#'];
```

I want to create a new array based on which of these checkboxes are selected and essentially make an array of arrays. I've tried the following code for that but it is not working:

```
var newArray = [];
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(){
    newArray.push($(this).val());
});
```

I can hard code newArray as follows:

```
var newArray = [value1, value2, value3];
```

After the newArray is populated, I want to loop through the values of the arrays contained in newArray to select random indices and push them into randArray. This part works if I hard code newArray as follows:

```
var newArray = [itemC, item!, item1]
```

But it will not work if I try to map the checkbox values to newArray. Once I have populated newArray I want to make sure that at least one item from each of the subsets in newArray are included in randArray. The part I am having difficulty with currently is getting newArray populated with the subsets based on what is checked.

An example of what I am trying to accomplish is similar to what is found at http://passwordsgenerator.net/

Comment: What do you want in newArray when a checkbox is not checked?

Comment: When checkboxes are not checked it should just be an empty array.

Comment: JavaScript does not have a way to access the value of a variable using another variable that contains the name of the first. This concept is called "variable variables" in PHP, but JS does not have this "feature". You should abandon the use of variables named "value1", "value2" and "value3" and instead use an object as an associative array and then do lookups based on the checkbox values. Ex: var values = { 'value1': ['item1', ...], 'value2': ['itemA', ...], 'value3': ['item!', ...] }; Whenever you have two variables named "something1" and "something2", you're probably doing the wrong thing!

Comment: I think this gives me the right direction to follow. Thank you, Nate.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax does *not* set the checkbox value to that of the js variable having the name `value1`:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="value1">Value 1
```

You might need something like this instead:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="item1,item2,item3">Value 1
<input type="checkbox" value="itemA,itemB,itemC">Value 2
<input type="checkbox" value="item!,item@,item#">Value 3
```

Then your newArray creation looks like this:

```
var newArray = [];
$('input[type=checkbox]').map(function () {
    var $cb = $(this);
    if ($cb.is(":checked")) {
        newArray.push($cb.val().split(','));
    } else {
        newArray.push([]);
    }
});
```

See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/slippery_pete/ddpnhww5/1/

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that I want to make sure that when I loop through newArray, that at least one value from each of the subsets is included in the output. If I ask for an output that is 3 characters long, the output could potentially all belong to the same subset instead of giving me a random value from each checkbox selected.

Comment: @gjanden that has nothing to do with the question you asked.  Maybe you should update the question as well as add sample output.  I am not sure what you are asking for anymore ;)